# Is the following true $|z|^n=|z^n|$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Proof attempt:

$|z^n|=|z\cdot z \cdot \cdot \cdot z|=|z|\cdot|z|\cdot \cdot \cdot|z|=|z|^n$

So the property is true only for $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @Guy : No it isn't. See my answer.

Comment: That would *only* be correct if you first proved that $|a \cdot b|=|a| \cdot |b|$ and used that as the base case for a proof by induction.

Comment: It is actually true for all integers $n$, at least of $z\neq 0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews and $z^{-n}=\frac{1}{z^n}$ right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, for nonzero complex numbers $z^n = \exp(n \log(z))$, using any branch of the logarithm of $z$.

Thus $$ \left| z^n \right| = \exp(\text{Re}(n \log(z)))$$
while
$$ |z|^n = \exp(n \log |z|) = \exp(n \text{Re}(\log(z)))$$

The two are equal if and only if $\text{Re}(n \log(z)) = n \text{Re}(\log(z)) + 2 m \pi i$ for some integer $m$.  There are two cases where this occurs:

1. $n$ is real.
2. $\log(z)$ is real, i.e. $z$ is real and positive, with $\text{Im}(n) = - 2 m \pi/\log(z)$.

Comment: If we take any branch of the log of $z$ we can use the property of $log(z)^n=nlog(z)$?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not correct.

You have assumed what you are trying to prove in the second equality.

You should use an inductive proof, after proving that $|z_1z_2|=|z_1||z_2|$.

Comment: Where is the *inequality*?

Comment: @JaideepKhare : "Equality" was intended. Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have assumed that $|a\cdot b|=|a|\cdot|b|$, thanks

Comment: You need to assume $|ab|=|a|\cdot |b|$, @MPW. $|z^2|=|z|^2$ is not enough to get this result.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : Yes, you are correct. Editing my answer, thanks.